# Issue with cropping picture from mysql database using PHP? Image shows up black?

Tags: php, mysql, image

Im having a weird problem retrieving/cropping a smaller version of an original image from mysql database. Kind of new to this and need some help.

I have a script that uploads an image to a database (the original image) as well as a smaller, cropped image to be used as a profile image and that kind of thing. Here is that code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
{
$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$maxsize = 99999999;
$temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$file_extension = end($temporary);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < $maxsize)//Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
&& in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {

$size = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$type = $size['mime'];
$imgfp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$size = $size[3];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$sql = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","sqlserver");
$imgfp64 = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($imgfp));
$update = "UPDATE sqlserver.imageblob set image='".$imgfp64."', image_type='".$type."', image_name='".$name."', image_size='".$size."' where user_id=".$account['id'];
$sql->query($update);
```

This is the part where scaling takes place:

```
//small image
    $w=50;$h=50;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $r = $width / $height;

        if ($w/$h > $r) { 
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }

    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($dst,null);
    $dst=ob_get_clean();

    $dst = base64_encode($dst);
            $update2 = "UPDATE sqlserver.imageblob set chatimage='".$dst."' where user_id=".$account['id'];

            $sql->query($update2);
```

And here is the result with only SOME images -

[image]

The original is not black. I read this post [PHP: black image when cropping using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442418/php-black-image-when-cropping-using-php) and think the script might be cropping outside the picture. What can I change in my code to mitigate this?

How can I make it scale down and crop the image from the image not outside?

Comment: Too hard to debug in present form.  Give us a [mcve], indented reasonably.  It really is worth it.

Comment: Sorry; I thought the code was minimal. I broke it up - the second part is really where the issue is occurring